# how do I switch to "full screen view" in flash that was created Ming php

Tags: php, facebook, flash, libming

my facebook application is  posting an SWF on user wall the SWF is created in PHP with Ming (good decision?)

I want to make a button that switch the view to full screen mode, do you know how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't mark this as dupe because of the bounty, so:

1. Make sure you have 'allowFullScreen' as true in your flash parameters
2. Create a button whose code is: 
   `stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;`

See [Adobe's Docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageDisplayState.html) for more information

Comment: do you know how to write this in PHP::Ming  ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, but this link I found on Google ( http://www.spinics.net/lists/ming-users/msg00052.html ) seems to suggest you can include actionscript pretty easily in your code

Answer (score 1):

You can't, Facebook is blocking you doing that. In order this to work you need just like @lgy says to set `<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />`. Facebook will not let you doing it, they only load your swf when user click on it(So the swf files will not be able to play any sound like it was in the old Facebook days) and they will set this parameter to false.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
$m = new SWFMovie();
// your code here..
$m->add(new SWFAction("stage.displayState = 'fullScreen';"));
$m->nextFrame();
// your code here
```